# text in the tablayout is not show correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a 11 `Fragment` in the `viewPager`, and when `tablayout` want to show these 11 fragment name , their text not show correctly.

this is the screenshot of my problem :

[image]

and this is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/xmlDrawerLayoutRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/xmlToolbarMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <!-- navigation opener -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnHomeToolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"/>
            <!-- app name -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttitleToolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            <!-- search box-->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSearchToolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <!-- Tablayout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/xmlTabLayoutMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/xmlToolbarMain"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <!-- ViewPager -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/xmlViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/xmlTabLayoutMain"/>

        <!-- navigationDrawer -->

        <!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/xmlNavigation"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="198dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="start"-->
            <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_view"-->
            <!--app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and I set this on my tablayout in the `MainActivity.java` but still i have a problem  :

```
 appTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not show correctly'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use like that

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/xmlTabLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xmlToolbarMain"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

also try to use if not working

```
app:tabGravity="fill"
```

tabMode will make your tab scrollable.So it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom style for your text and there define all the constraints like normal text view attributes. then just set tab text appearance to your custom style.

Your tab layout will be like -

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    />
```

And in your style.xml file define the style, like this -

```
    <style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    </style>
```